# Foreach doesn't add each item from foreach to ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I am sure I am just thinking about this far too much, but I am trying to get a list and everything works except for one thing.  And I know why it's doing it, it's getting the last item of the `foreach` that is assigned to the outside of the loop and returning just that one item.  But I want to to return ALL of them.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var cheeses = _repository.GetAllYearSetupIds();
var gouda = new CollectionsManagementViewModel();
var yearSetupId = 0;
foreach(var cheddar in cheeses)
{
    yearSetupId = cheddar.YearSetupId;
    gouda = _repository.GetOverdueBalances(page, pageLength, yearSetupId, balancefilter, sort, direction == Constants.ascending, spreadsheetType);
    gouda.Title = title + " Management";
}      
return View("CollectionsManagement", gouda);
```

Comment: It's impossible to really understand your question without a good [mcve]. But it seems you have a method that returns a single object. What makes you think it's possible for it to do anything _but_ do that? I.e. _"return ALL of them"_? Even if it did return a collection, what would you do with that? You're going to need to be a lot more specific. Fix your question so it includes a good MCVE, and a much better description of what the code does now, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you're having trouble figuring out.

Comment: What is the `View` class here? Did you mean to tag your question with [tag:asp.net-mvc], rather than [tag:model-view-controller]? (I see Sergey changed the tag, just as I posted this comment...so one hopes that's correct. Your question would be more clear if tagged correctly.)

Comment: foreach doesn't work with cheese datatypes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you are updating single instance of `CollectionsManagementViewModel` named `gouda` on each iteration in your loop. After the loop `gouda` will have the value from the last iteration.

You should create new instance of `CollectionsManagementViewModel` on each iteration and add this instance to the list of view models. Of course naming should be meaningful:

```
// list of models, because you want ALL of them
var managementModels = new List<CollectionsManagementViewModel>();
var setupIds = _repository.GetAllYearSetupIds();

foreach(var setupId in setupIds)
{
   // new model created for each setup id
   var managementModel = _repository.GetOverdueBalances(page, pageLength,
            setupId.YearSetupId, balancefilter,
            sort, direction == Constants.ascending,
            spreadsheetType);

   managementModel.Title = title + " Management";
   managementModels.Add(managementModel); // add model to list
}

// pass collection to view
return View("CollectionsManagement", managementModels);
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped.  I was so unsure of how to do it I got tripped up in my own brain.

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CollectionsManagementViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CollectionsManagementViewModel'.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hope following code may helpful for you

```
var cheeses = _repository.GetAllYearSetupIds();
var lstgouda = new  List<CollectionsManagementViewModel>();  //make a list
var yearSetupId = 0;
foreach(var cheddar in cheeses)
{

    var gouda = new  CollectionsManagementViewModel(); 
    yearSetupId = cheddar.YearSetupId;
    gouda = _repository.GetOverdueBalances(page, pageLength, yearSetupId, balancefilter, sort, direction == Constants.ascending, spreadsheetType);
    gouda.Title = title + " Management";
    lstgouda.add(gouda);  //add it to list
}      
return View("CollectionsManagement", lstgouda);
```

Thanks
Karthik